# How to find whether a 3D object is enclosed within another 3D object?

Tags: geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems

I have two closed 3D objects each having a collection of points.

Obj1: $[x_{11}, y_{11}, z_{11}]\ldots[x_{1n}, y_{1n}, z_{1n}]$

Obj2: $[x_{21}, y_{21}, z_{21}]\ldots[x_{2n}, y_{2n}, z_{2n}]$

**Is there a generic way/algorithm to find if Obj1 is inside/outside Obj2 ?**

I have already figured an algorithm to find if Obj1 is intersecting Obj2 or not. Timing is not a constraint here; so I can apply Brute force technique.

Comment: What is "inside"? Do you mean that all points of Obj1 must be among the points of Obj2? Or that they are _within the convex hull_ of Obj2? Or that Obj1 can be translated and/or rotated in such a way that anything of the above becomes true? Or something else entirely?

Comment: I meant they are within the convex hull of Obj2.

Comment: Then it must be relatively easy, especially if you would not object against a brute force solution. Just check for every point of Obj1 whether it is within the convex hull of Obj2. Detecting intersections is **way harder than that**; two convex hulls may intersect even if all points of Obj1 are outside of Obj2 and all points of Obj2 are outside of Obj1.

Comment: Thanks @ Ivan Neretin :)